# El método save() no actualiza la base de datos

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo un modelo al que agregué un nuevo campo que quiero que se actualice automáticamente, pero no lo hace.

Esta es la parte del modelo involucrada:

```
class ExpedienteDPI():
        folio = models.CharField(max_length=13)
        fecha_tramite = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
        fecha_notificacion_aclaracion = models.DateField(
            'TRÁMITE: Notificación',
            help_text='Fecha de notificación de aclaración al ciudadano AC',
            null=True, blank=True
        )
        # muchos campos mas
        # Siguen solo campos calculados
        delta_notificar = models.SmallIntegerField(
            help_text="Delta entre tramite y notificación",
            editable=False, null=True
        )
        completo = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(editable=False, null=False, default=0)
```

Este modelo tiene tiene sobreescribe el método `save()` para hacer algunos cálculos para llenar campos **que no son editables**, entre ellos `completo`.

```
        def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
            self.delta_notificar = delta(self.fecha_tramite, self.fecha_notificacion_aclaracion)
            # Muchos campos calculados
            if self.entidad == 29 and \
                    self.fecha_tramite and \
                    self.fecha_entrevista and \
                    self.fecha_envio_expediente and \
                    self.fecha_notificacion_aclaracion:
                self.completo = 1
            else:
                self.completo = 0
            super(ExpedienteDPI, self).save(force_insert=False, force_update=False)
```

En este ejemplo, el método `save()` funciona para el campo `delta_notificar` que calcula la diferencia entre dos fechas, **pero no funciona para el campo `completo`**.

He probado las condiciones de `completo` en un *shell* de Django, con esto:

```
for x in ExpedienteDPI.objects.all():
    if x.entidad == 29 and \
        x.fecha_tramite and \
        x.fecha_entrevista and \
        x.fecha_envio_expediente and \
        x.fecha_notificacion_aclaracion:
        if x.completo == 0:
            print(f'Completo vale {x.completo}. Cambiando {x.folio} a "Completo"')
            x.completo = 1
        else:
            print(f"{x.folio} - Completo")
    else:
        print(f"{x.folio} - Incompleto")
        x.completo = 0
    x.save(force_update=True)
```

Y funciona, ya que produce la salida esperada:

```
1729032100849 - Incompleto
Completo vale 0. Cambiando 1729012101027 a "Completo"
1729022401044 - Incompleto
1729032100652 - Incompleto
Completo vale 0. Cambiando 1729022200132 a "Completo"
1729032100109 - Incompleto
```

Pero en la base de datos, sigue siendo 0.

Entiendo que el problema no es mi base de datos PostgreSQL porque cuando actualizo con `UPDATE`, el registro se actualiza:

```
UPDATE dpi_expedientedpi
SET completo = 1
WHERE folio = '1729025301604'
SELECT folio, completo FROM dpi_expedientedpi WHERE folio = '1729025301604';
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme a encontrar mi error.

Comment: Lo primero con lo que podría ayudarte sería con esta línea: `super(ExpedienteDPI, self).save(force_insert=False, force_update=False)` trata de cuando llames al super no pasar esos valores forzados, simplemente si tu los recoges como parámetros pásalos ahí, cuando estás haciendo la prueba con el `force_update=True` no estas obteniendo el resultado deseado, quedaría así: `super(ExpedienteDPI, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)`

Comment: Gracias @GermanAlzate, ya lo intenté pero no funciona tampoco. Lo raro es que los cálculos previos, que calculan deltas, si que funcionan, solo ese campo no se actualiza.

Comment: ¿Has intentado usando `*args` y `**kwargs`? Se me ocurre que no se esté pasando algo que debería llegar: `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):` y `super(ExpedienteDPI, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Hola @César, también lo he intentado, igual sin éxito. Mañana actualizo la pregunta con las consultas SQL que genera el ORM.